# objects in scene are not appearing in final render but are in render view - cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am using Cycles 2.79 to make a render for a customer and when I render it, only renders one head from one of the various characters and scene objects. **I show that on the first photo.**

But in render view it shows the whole scene which is shown **on the second photo**.

[image]

[image]

I need help on how to fix this!

Comment: See all of them camera icons on the right? Those determine what gets rendered. If they are switched off the object will not render.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what is going on but it may not work in that version but if it does:
This is a very common problem and easily fixed, firstly go into the top right and open an outliner window.[image]

Then that window should show which parts of the render are visible, if not open the tab shown here[image]

This will then reveal which items are included in the render and which aren't by a greyed out camera icon.[image]
Change this icon to the non greyed out camera and the objects should appear in your render.

Good luck!